# org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NoInteractionsWanted: Unit Test failed - MVI arhictecture

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have implemented an MVI arhitecture for an android application, but I can not write any successful tests.

This is an example:

```
fun verifyLoadStateSuccess() {

    val loading= State(isLoading = true)
    val loaded = State(list)

    whenever(listUseCase.loadList()).thenReturn(Observable.just(list))

    viewModel.dispatch(Action.Load)
    testSchedulerRule.triggerActions()

    inOrder(testObserver) {
        verify(testObserver).onChanged(loading)
        verify(testObserver).onChanged(loaded)
    }

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(testObserver) // if i comment this line, the test pass ok
}
```

The error that I get is saying that :

```
No interactions wanted here:
-> at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.MockitoKt.verifyNoMoreInteractions(Mockito.kt:258)
But found this interaction on mock 'observer':
-> at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
***
For your reference, here is the list of all invocations ([?] - means unverified).
1. [?]-> at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
```

I have run the code with debugger, and checked on `reducer`, how may times is called and with what values for `state`, but it's only twice with the proper values.

I don't get what is that `considerNotify` method that it says it's invoked and how can I add it to my test.

Answer (score 1):

it means that your observer onChanged is being called with more events . hold a break point in considerNotify method of live data while you run the test. you will see that more events than what you think are being fired so the test fails.